# Blender FBX exports to Unity3D have incomplete animation sequences

Tags: unity, animation, blender, rigging

Using Blender, I have rigged and animated this model with this attack action.

[image: Animation in Blender]

I exported this model to an FBX format and imported the said FBX file into my Unity3D project. However, when I imported it, I noticed that the animation sequence is incomplete:

[image: Imported FBX in Unity]

As you can see, the sword does not animate correctly and remains unmoved in its original position.

In Blender, the sword and scabbard are animated in Pose mode with IK and other constraints. However, as I understand it, FBX bakes these constraints into the animation, so I'm not sure if that causes the issue.

**Why is the sword not animating correctly? How do I fix this so that the Unity animation is 100% faithful to the Blender animation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's causing the problem is setting the `Animation Type` of the rig to `Humanoid`. I guess this causes the animation to lose its mapping to non-humanoid related bones.

What fixes the issue is setting the `Animation Type` to `Generic` like so:

[image: Correct import setting]